# html- how to pass state of checkbox to search query SQL statement?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Im trying to pass the state of a checkbox to a search query(SQL statement) in another file.

I have two files, the checkbox is defined in one and the other has the SQL statement.
When the checkbox is checked and the search button pressed, i want it to load all rows with 'Y'. This is part of a search function i have but I can't seem to get the checkboxes to work like the input boxes, when i search for stuff.

---

invoice.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate() {
    if (document.getElementById('box1').checked) {
        alert("checked");
    } else {
        alert("Not checked.")
    }
}
</script>



<td><input type="checkbox" name="chkbox2" value="box2a" id="box1"  onclick="validate()"> Checked</td>
```

---

invoice_search.jsp

```
   <c:if test="${checked param.chkbox2}">

<sql:query var ="NameCheck" scope = "session" dataSource = "${bookdB}">

    SELECT Job_ID
        FROM Jobs
    WHERE Job_ID LIKE 'Y'

    <sql:param value = "%${param.job_id}%" />

</sql:query>

  </c:if>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Value of checkbox must be 'Y' ?
checkboxes are only sent if they are checked, so you need a hidden input with the same name and value 'N'... <!> just pay attention to put the hidden input BEFORE the checkbox, otherwise the value is ignored.

Comment: Hi SparK, Thanks for getting back to us. Im using MS access as my database, When the checkbox is ticked, i want it to load all rows when the field name is equal to 'Y'. Access can't seem to store the tick, so i thought using 'Y' or 'N' it would be able to define if the checkbox was true or false(ticked or not ticked).

Comment: i have another checkbox called "Not checked" to display any field equal to 'N'. but i thought if i got help with the first checkbox, i could do the others. thanks

Comment: in that case you may be able to use checkboxes with the same name in an array:
`<input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Y">` and `<input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="N">`... you may notice them both have same name, this is returned as an array in which you can: `select something from a_table where your_field in(cbox_values);`

not sure if that's what you want

Comment: K, Thanks. i'll try that. But how would I read the checkbox from the other JSP page?, so the SQL statement would load the 'Y', instead of the value. if thats possible?

Comment: not sure how to read them in JSP, all I know is that (at least in php) it gives me an array instead of a string value for the "cbox" parameter... I'm sure jsp can handle arrays in forms, I just don't know how it does it.

Comment: That makes two of us, haha. Thanks for the help SparK.